# Normal ordering of operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, vacuum, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

Just a quick question regarding normal ordering. To begin given a field $\phi(x)$ we can normal order it in respect to some state $|G\rangle$:
$$:\phi(x):=\phi(x)-\langle \phi(x)\rangle $$
Typically we let our normal ordering be in respect to the ground state of the system.

I tend to let myself get tripped up in trivial matters and am just wondering if anything changes when we start normal ordering operators in respect to our ground state. **Clearly certain expectation values vanish but does anything significant ever happen when taking expectation values between normal ordered operators opposed to just the operators themselves? Do I ever need to be careful or can I calculate using all the same tools I would use otherwise, like Wick's theorem, etc.?**

**As an extra aside:** One instance where I feel like this normal ordering matters is in a Luttinger liquid and the appearance of a Swinger anomaly when computing the commutation relations of our current operators. As I recall, Mattis and Lieb corrected Luttinger's mistake in neglecting some subtle aspect of filling the right and left moving states for antiparticles and particles in the ground state. I think these states are connected, and can be realized by considering the effect of an electric field (spectral flow?).